# Composer: The package has modified files

Tags: composer

I am using Composer "composer update" via a cronjob to daily update an instance of software and thus run on master. About once a month this fails because Composer returns the following prompt:

> The package has modified files
>
> M modifiedfile.php
>
> Discard changes [y,n,v,s,?]?

So no update is performed. This is a bit annoying. Is there a way to force the update even with modified files? [Documentation at Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update) suggests that this is not possible though I cannot believe that it should not.

So I am trying my luck here: Is there something like "composer update --force" or some sort of trick around or am I looking at a lost cause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `--no-interaction` for this.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-no-interaction

(old topic, but pops-up in Google without an answer)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This flag will be useful from time to time. That's the commit that brought it:https://github.com/composer/composer/commit/83ea90296e001c3df6f1eb9933db65c1d45a1b37

Answer (score 0):

`--no-interaction` answers `N` to this question - meaning that the `composer install` command fails.

There is no option which might answer `Y` or `--force` the install.

The only workaround seems to be `rm -R /vendor/` before running `composer install`.